# How computers compare values at the atomic level

Tags: transistors

How does a computer compare two values at the level of electrical current flowing for value 'a' and for value 'b'?  Here is a diagram:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator#

Because the Wikipedia explanation is confusing.. Or in other words: how does the computer comparitor work at the atomic level like at the level of physics, because the diagram says it takes two voltages or currents and compares them and outposts a digital answer..

Comment: You are mixing multiple concepts here. You mix up analog subtraction and digital subtraction. Subtraction of two currents (or voltages) is analog. Digital computers do not do this. They subtract binary numbers using binary logic. You could do it with electromechanical relays or air valves. Furthermore, although signals can be represented as current they are more often represented as voltages. You then also throw in how a CPU assembly instruction works which is far removed from the rest. What is it you want to know exactly? Because you do not need CPU instructions to do digital subtraction.

Comment: Dknguyen- "They subtract binary numbers using binary logic. "-- how then is binary logic done at the lowest level..as in they had to engineer it some way to work at the level of atoms. I just don't understand how it works at the lowest level of abstraction.

Comment: Binary logic doesn't rely on transistors or atoms at all. Just on/off switches which transistors and a number of other devices can do. In binary numbers digits are only 0 and 1 so there's a very few set number of cases for the number of possible operation between two digits and you can map it out. For example, for addition 0+0=0, 0+1=1, 1+1=0 with a carry. That's it. And you can do that with logic gates whether they are made of relays or transistors or something else. There's no actual subtraction of electrical signals or anything.

Comment: Ok thx, but how does a computer comparitor work at the hardware level. Like here is a diagram: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator#

Comment: "I searched for circuit diagrams or examples with transistors but nothing came up" - https://www.megaprocessor.com/

Comment: `How computers compare values at the atomic level` ... that is like asking `how does a waterwheel drive a grindstone at an atomic level?`

Comment: That Wikipedia comparator page discusses analog comparators - no computer involved.  The comparators discussed there compare two analog voltages.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT85.pdf) is the logic diagram for comparing two 4-bit numbers in terms of simple logic gates (can be expanded to any number of bits by cascading multiple units together):

[image]

If you want to know how gates work at a transistor level, you can dig down into that (maybe start with CD40xx CMOS gates which often had internal schematics in the datsheets).

If you want to know how transistors work at an 'atomic' level, you'll have to crack a book on solid-state physics. I'm fond of Kittel but there are probably more recent books that are more available.

Comment: Thx the answer "solid state physics" was the answer I was looking for..

Answer (score 3):

Binary logic and binary arithmetic does not rely on addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, or any similar operation on electrical signals at all. It can be done with anything that can switch whether it be transistors, vacuum tubes, electromechanical relays, pneumatic valves, hydraulic valves, etc.

When you are working with binary numbers each digit can only be either 0 or 1. That makes the possible combinations possible for an operation between two digits very simple and easy to map out (well, not for division):

[image]
[image]
[image]

The logic: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/binary_arithmetic.htm

That means you can literally just use something like a look up table or come up with devices that take two digital signals representing two digits and based on their combination just arbitrarily spit out the result you want to match your logic (in this case the logic is binary arithmetic). Logic gates are one way to do this. They aren't constructed to actually add or subtract or anything like that. They are constructed to arbitrarily produce the output you want based on the input to match your logical framework.

That means any device you do this with can be made to do binary arithmetic. For example, both transistors and relays can conduct or block current based on a signal so both can be used to produce specific outputs based on specific combinations of inputs:
[image]
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schematic-representation-of-electromagnetic-relays-and-two-logic-gates-The-upper-left_fig2_273675456

Here are some logic gates that exist: [image]
https://instrumentationtools.com/logic-gates-and-truth-tables/

So if you take a look at the table for binary addition (ignore the carry column for now), you will notice that the inputs and outputs match an OR gate. Which means you can use an OR gate to do single-digit binary addition. The OR gate isn't actually adding anything, but it just happens to produce the outputs you need to match the framework required for adding. And how do you build an OR gate? Well one way is with the relays as shown above, and you can do nearly the same thing with transistors too.

**UPDATE:**
You asked how a comparator works. For a **DIGITAL comprator**, same idea as previously discussed. Let's focus on just one digit. If your only possible digits are 0 and 1, the possible cases to compare are very simple. So again, you figure out what those combinations are.

```
A > B = C
[A,B,C]
[0,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,0]
```

That's your logical framework. Now you have to think of a circuit or machine that produces an output C with the two inputs A and B that match up. This circuit doesn't need to actually compare anything. It just needs to produce the desired output based on the desired input. In this case it's not one of the common logic gates, but there are systematic methods to come up with a group of logic gates that produce the any combination of outputs based on any combination of inputs.

I won't explain how here. It's not complicated but requires background to understand. I can give you keywords if you're interested: "Sum of products", "product of sums", and "Karnaugh maps".

---

However, if we're talking about an **ANALOG comparator** (which is what you actually linked to when asking), that compares digital signals, this does actually subtract something. It's more complicated than I want to really talk about. But it uses a "differential pair" which is a transistor configuration. Basically it forces a fixed amount of current between two transistors. Each transistor takes one voltage signal as the input. If the two transistors conduct equally because the signal to both are equal, the current between the two is identical. But if the voltage is different they conduct differently and that total fixed current is shoved more towards one transistor than the other. That difference in current can be extracted to produce a voltage that tells you which signal is higher or lower. This is oversimplified.

[image]
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-basic-mosfet-differential-pair/